# Most effective way to remove mold from microgreens

Tags: mold

I've seen a few ways to remove mold from microgreens, but I'm not sure how to do this exactly to be harmless for my customers. I've read this [article](https://www.healthline.com/health/food-grade-hydrogen-peroxide) and as far as I understand I need to use 35% since this is for food grade. Do you know any others ways to fight the mold or how exactly should I use peroxide? Any resources with information are welcome, thanks

From the resource:

> Hydrogen peroxide (H2O2) is a clear, colorless, odorless liquid. It’s
> a combination of hydrogen and oxygen and is available in many
> strengths (indicated by the percentage of dilution with water).
>
> One dilution of hydrogen peroxide is 35 percent H2O2 and 65 percent
> water. Food producers use 35 percent H2O2 for a variety of purposes,
> including processing cheese and bleaching wheat flour. It’s also used
> to kill microorganisms in food packaging materials.
>
> This 35 percent dilution is called “food grade” in part because it
> doesn’t contain certain stabilizers:
>
> acetanilide phenol sodium stanate tetrasodium pyrophosphate